# Enabling Auto-Complete for custom syntax in Sublime text

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I cannot get Sublime auto complete to work properly for custom syntaxes. For example, this is what happens when the syntax is set to Javascript:

[image: working in js]

When the syntax is set to my custom syntax, these types of suggestions never show up. Custom snippets show up just fine, but variables found in the file do not show up properly. When I click [CTRL+SPACE], this is what I get:

[image]

For some reason, single characters will show up, but not whole words. For the syntax, I copied the `Completion Rules.tmPreferences`, `Symbol List.tmPreferences`, etc. directly from [here](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/tree/master/JavaScript) so that all should be fine (although messing around with them didn't seem to do anything).

I have tried adding the syntax to `auto_complete_selector` in settings, but it does not work. I use the package `All Autocomplete`, and deleting this did not change anything.

Comment: Is your custom syntax available publicly? If not, what is the base scope? For example, Python is `source.python`, JS is `source.js`, etc.

Comment: That looks suspiciously like your syntax is scoping characters one at a time instead of symbols as a whole.

Comment: @MattDMo, the syntax highlighting is for a completely custom language, ergo it's a custom scope (in this case, it's `source.nt`)